# Нужно добавить компонент, после 6-ти блоков с классом "cart"

Tags: reactjs, dom, компоненты, render

Нужно добавить компонент "MatchesSlider" после 6-ти блоков с классом "cart", которые 'смапились' от массива. В итоге мы будем иметь много карточек '.cart' и по середине (после 6 ти карточек) будет этот компонент.

```
import React from 'react';
import './News.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

import MatchesSlider from '../Main/MatchesSlider/MatchesSlider';

const News = () => {
    const[news, setNews] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/myNews')
        .then(response => {
            setNews(response.data && response.data.reverse().map((e) => {
                let date = new Date(e.date);
                let day = String(date.getDate()).length < 2 ? '0' + String(date.getDate()) : String(date.getDate());
                let month = String(date.getMonth()).length < 2 ? '0' + String(date.getMonth()) : String(date.getMonth());
                let year = date.getFullYear();
                let hours = String(date.getHours()).length < 2 ? '0' + String(date.getHours()) : String(date.getHours());
                let minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).length < 2 ? '0' + String(date.getMinutes()) : String(date.getMinutes());

                const animIn = () => { // anim mouse in
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} .img img`).css({'transform': 'scale(1.04)'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id}`).css({'boxShadow': '0px 0px 15px 1px #000'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} h3`).css({'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'}).css({'color': 'rgb(224, 164, 79)'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} .img img`).css({'opacity': '1'});
                }
                const animOut = () => { // anim mouse out
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} .img img`).css({'transform': 'scale(1)'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id}`).css({'boxShadow': '0px 0px 0px 0px #000'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} h3`).css({'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'}).css({'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
                    $(`.newsHr #${'id' + e.id} .img img`).css({'opacity': '0.8'});
                }
                return  <div key={'key' + e.id} className="cart" id={'id' + e.id} onMouseEnter={animIn} onMouseLeave={animOut}> // тут формируется блок который рендериться в итоге
                            <Link to={`/news/${e.id}`}>
                                <div className="img"><img alt={e.title} src={e.img} /></div>
                                <h3>{e.title}</h3>
                                <span>{day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' | ' + hours + ':' + minutes}</span>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
            }));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id='news' className='newsHr'>
            <h1 className="pageName">Новости</h1>
            <section>
                {news}
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};

export default News;
```

Comment: В методе map есть index итерируемого элемента. Проверяйте по индексу номер и дополнительно добавляйте его при возврате значения map. Однако, JQUERY, так же должен использоваться для доступа и модификаций элементов DOM в REACT

Comment: [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) `{news.splice(5, 0, <MatchesSlider />)}`

Comment: В первом сообщении опечатка. JQUERY НЕ должен использоваться в REACT приложении для доступа и модификации DOM элементов

Comment: Подскажите в примере, тогда как сделать, чтобы получилось подобное?  С методом splice не получилось

Answer (score 1):

### Как узнать номер элемента в итерируемом массиве методом **map**

> Метод **map массива** принимает 3 аргумента, элемент массива, индекс массива и сам массив -> **.map(item, index, arr)**

Вам необходимо в методе **map** смотреть на второй аргумент (индекс текущего элемента) и если он 6й, то выводить дополнительный блок. 
Т.к. нумерация идет с 0, то увеличиваем на 1. Что бы узнать, 6й ли он по списку, делим на 6 и получаем остаток от деления. Если 0, то это 6й элемент.

Ниже пример данной реализации.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  arr.push({
    id: i,
    value: `value ${i}`
  })
}

const Match = ({ num }) => {
  return <div>Скоро новый матч #{num}!</div>
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(arr);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item, index) => {
        return <><div>
        <span>{item.id}</span>
        <span>{item.value}</span>
        </div>
        {!((index + 1) % 6) && <div><Match num={index} /></div>}
        </>
    })}
    </div>
  );
}
```