# Добавление нового контейнера в тексте с разделением и смещением текста в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Можно ли как-то разделить сам текст на две части, как показано на прототипе ниже?

[image: Полный текст]
[image: Смещённый текст с новым блоком]

В принципе получить количество строк можно нехитрым способом, но что с этим делать дальше?

```typescript
  const textRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const text = textRef.current;
    if (!text) return;
    let height = text.offsetHeight;
    let lineHeight = Number(
      window
        .getComputedStyle(text)
        .getPropertyValue("line-height")
        .replace("px", "")
    );
    let lines = Math.floor(height / lineHeight);
  }, [textRef]);
```

Comment: Разбили текст и положили в массив. Далее в массив в нужное мето добавили картинки(как я понимаю суть в этом), затем циклом выводите текст из массива. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463272/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-6-%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-cart/1463363#1463363) немного похожую задачу решали, только  там добалялся блока после каждого 6го блока

Comment: В таком случае возникает вопрос как можно разбить большой текст на строки подходящего размера без большой потери производительности? Пока что в голову приходит только каждый раз добавлять новый параграф и уже в него добавлять слова со сравнением длины строки и ширины контейнера

Comment: Ну за вашу логику отображения уже не подскажу. т.к. не известно, что такое "подходящий размер"(три ореха это куча?), причем здесь длина и ширина контейнера... Ведь может быть так, что в тексте не нужны картинки, а где то нужны после каждой строки. Поэтому вам предстоит предумать логику, как и покаким ключам/условиям бить текст и как туда добавлять нужные вам значения.